# Why does my docker daemon run the container as an arbitrary non-docker user?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On an Ubuntu machine, issue a working 'docker run' as the 'app' user who is part of the 'docker' group.

It started up fine, however when looking at the process tree it started as another arbitrary user 'splunk' that was also on my system:

```
root      3573  0.1  0.6 337532 24216 ?        Ssl  01:28   0:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon
root      3678  1.0  0.3 177280 13132 ?        Sl   01:30   0:00  \_ docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.1.2.3 -container-port 8080
splunk    3686  5.0  0.2  52144 10220 ?        Ssl  01:30   0:00  \_ ruby /app/foo/build/bin/my_run_script
splunk    3702  0.0  0.0   4440   656 ?        S    01:30   0:00      \_ sh -c bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c config/unicorn.rb
splunk    3703 76.0  1.6 301208 63684 ?        Sl   01:30   0:03          \_ unicorn master -p 8080 -c config/unicorn.rb
```

I understand that issuing the  'docker run' command as the 'app' user simply instructs the daemon on what script to start on a particular image. The daemon (which runs as root) then would go out and run the process as another user. I would expect this to be the issuing 'app' user and not some other random user.

Why would this be happening? I checked that the UIDs for the two users are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not necessarily, what does the `Dockerfile` look like for the container you are running? This is an example of a `Dockerfile` `RUN` command that would run as a different user:

```
/bin/su -c 'ruby /app/foo/build/bin/my_run_script' someuser
```

Or you can run your container like this:

```
docker run -u="myuser" mycontainer "ruby /app/foo/build/bin/my_run_script"
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/run/#user)

It's likely that the container that you are using was created with the `USER` directive and set to `splunk` or `uid`

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#user)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually don't run 'my_run_script' from within the Dockerfile. I call it manually by appending it to my 'docker run' command.

Comment: @wuunderbar what does the full docker command look like ? Also what are the docker daemon options? Can you post them ? What linux distro you are using? What docker version?

Comment: I actually figured out the issue, but not sure how to resolve. It seems that by default docker daemon is starting container user UIDs as 999. (If I delete the splunk user, which I had manually set to as UID 999 way back when and restart the container, it shows '999' instead of 'splunk'). So I need a way to change the starting UID for docker daemon's conatiners. Running through documentation but can't find it so far. Do you happen to know?

Comment: @wuunderbar ah ok.. modified my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Yes! You got it. Was also solved via this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788079/where-can-i-configure-the-start-user-uid-for-docker-containers