# Where can I configure the start user UID for Docker containers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

Where can I configure the start user UID for Docker containers? By default it uses UID 999 which conflicts with some other users on my system.

Comment: Have you considered setting the UID using the USER statement in the Dockerfile? See: https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, run the following command:

```
RUN groupadd -r -g 1234 newusername && useradd -r -u 1234 -g newusername newusername
USER newusername
```

This will create a user `newusername` with GID 1234 and UID 1234, then run the container with a default user `newusername`.